# why fails create-react-app with "errno ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! network request"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Have been trying to run React on my local system using the Hyper terminal
I typed the code: `npx create-react-app my-apps`
it keeps flagging these errors below:

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@svgr%2fplugin-svgo failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.26.35:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Edmund Obinna\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-21T12_17_44_191Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-apps/ from C:\Users\Edmund Obinna
Done."
```

Comment: Please change the title to make it more likely future readers can find it via websearch

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
npm config rm proxy
```

then:

```
npm config rm https-proxy
```

(https://howtodoinjava.com/angular/npm-install-hung/)

Comment: I did as you suggested and it gave me this new error:

Comment: npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Edmund Obinna\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-22T09_20_09_248Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting app/ from C:\Users\Edmund Obinna
Done.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, I was not behind any proxy, and fixed it by just updating node and npm.

Install n:

```
npm i -g n
```

Update node using n:

```
n lts
```

Update npm:

```
npm i -g npm
```

And then create your react app:

```
npx create-react-app my-apps
```

I would also suggest using yarn:

```
yarn create react-app my-apps
```